# Javascript a.hover doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I took this css theme which is working with javascript and i have a problem with the `a.hover` (not working):

http://cssdeck.com/labs/zg4cr9hu

This is the first time i use javascript and i think that the problem comes from the `jquery.min.js` file i took from the library...

In the `<head>` i wrote in the html page :

```
<script src="script_intro.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

Is this where the error comes from ? Or should i put something in the js file that i didn't touch (seems good without errors)...

Thanks in advance for answers :)

Comment: What's supposed to be happening?

Comment: What browser are you using? Because when i hover with mouse it works. It changes the shade of the color.

Comment: it is working, for me (Chrome Mac)

Comment: Hovering over the tiles causes them to light up for me in both Firefox 37 and IE 10 (Windows for both)

Comment: Do you have any console errors? if you are in chrome it should be f12

Comment: If you're talking about the mouse in the element, it should be `a:hover` not `a.hover`. The dot means it has the class `hover`, not the state.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using `jQuery` in your first script you have to **invert the lines**, `jQuery` first and after the scripts that make use of `jQuery`.

```
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script src="script_intro.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```